# Big ibdata1 file on MySql affects on database performance?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a database with big ibdata1 file, and for now my system seems slower. Does big ibdata1 file affect on my database performance ?

Answer (score 1):

A large ibdata1 alone doesn't have any impact to performance.

Growth in the ibdata1 file can be caused by a lot of unpurged row versions and unmerged change buffer entries. The impact to performance of these unfinished changes is that queries may need to merge data entries from multiple parts of the file in a just-in-time fashion.

Gradually, InnoDB will clean this up in the background, but that can take many minutes or hours, depending on how much database activity created the back-log of changes.

If you don't want to wait for that, you can dump and restore your data, which will rebuild the tablespace including indexes.

Comment: hi @bill-karwin, so is it just space issue ?

Answer (score 0):

First check innodb_file_per_table variable, it seems it is off in your server. Due to this all data is storing in single file .ibdata1, If you set this variable on then each table data will be stored its own .ibd file.

If there is frequent updation and deletion in your tables then your index will be fragmented and index will not be used properly (some time index file size will be increased and even index can take more time than table scan). Also db size will not be freed even so many rows deletion.

In this scenario you need to rebuild index, also need to gain freed space and for it you need to rebuild your db. You can achieve it by either optimize table, or alter any field, or dump/restore.

If your data will be stored in single file like .ibdata1 then even you have index/space issue with 1 table but you have to rebuild whole db. But if you use innodb_file_per_table then you need to just rebuild single table where is problem.

Hope this will help you analyze your problem.